# Funções com quantidade de argumentos "dinâmica"

Tags: r

quero construir uma função que pode ter o número de parâmetros variáveis, como a função `c`, e como acessar os endereços delas, por exemplo:

```
c(a = 1, b = 2, d = 9)
#acessar a, b e d
```

Tem alguma relação com os `...`? O que eles significam?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dot-dot-dot` ou `...` é chamado de **elipse**.

```
minha_funcao_com_elipse <- function(...) {
  input_list <- list(...)
  input_list
}
```

Veja o resultado desta função:

```
> minha_funcao_com_elipse(a = 1, b= 2, c= 3)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

Note que o comando `input_list <- list(...)` cria uma lista com todos os parâmetros que foram passados dentro da *elipse*.

Como `input_list` é uma lista comum do R, é fácil acessar os seus elementos. A função `c`, por exemplo poderia ser imitada da seguinte forma:

```
> c2 <- function(...) {
+   unlist(list(...))
+ }
> c2(a = 1, b= 2, c= 3, 5, 6)
a b c     
1 2 3 5 6
```

Vale a pena ler [esta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3083193/3297472). Uma outra boa referência é o [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) na sessão `...`.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode definir uma função usando o `...`, que pode ser usado para acessar argumentos passados explicitamente por nome. Para acessar os valores, você converte os `...` em uma lista (usando `list(...)`). O código abaixo mostra um exemplo:

```
c <- function(...) {
    args <- list(...)
    argNames <- names(args)
    print(argNames)
    sum(sapply(args, function(x) x))
}

c(a = 1, b = 4, d = 9)
```